# zsh completion: menu and unambiguous prefix with a single tab?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm in a folder where I have the following files:

```
aaa1  aaa2  aaa3  bbb1  bbb2  bbc1  bbc2
```

and I have typed `cd a` at the prompt. Currently,

- pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> completes to `cd aaa`
- then another <kbd>Tab</kbd> brings up the menu (`aaa1/  aaa2/  aaa3/`)
- and finally a third <kbd>Tab</kbd> completes to `cd aaa1/`
- and subsequent presses cycle through the menu

I'd like to combine the first and second <kbd>Tab</kbd>, so that:

- pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> completes to `cd aaa` *and* brings up the menu
- pressing another <kbd>Tab</kbd> completes to `cd aaa1/`
- subsequent presses cycle through the menu as usual

OR

- pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> completes to `cd aaa`
- pressing another <kbd>Tab</kbd> brings up the menu *and* completes to `cd aaa1/`
- subsequent presses cycle through the menu as usual

Is there any combination of `(un)setopt` or `zstyle` that can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, this method appears to get directly to selecting "aaa1" and being in a loop-on-the-menu-items mode:

```
exec zsh -f
zmodload zsh/complist
autoload -U compinit; compinit
bindkey "^I" menu-select
cd a
```

As does the `menucomplete` option:

```
exec zsh -f
autoload -U compinit; compinit
setopt menucomplete
cd a
```

There is an `autolist` option, but that only lists the options with input of `cd aaa` but not your desired `cd a` case. Hmm! How about this:

```
exec zsh -f
autoload -U compinit; compinit
setopt nolistambiguous
cd a
```

This completes to `cd aaa` and shows the "aaa*" directories.

Comment: `setopt nolistambiguous` works perfectly. Thanks!